# Geodesic beeing inextendible and incomplete

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, geodesics

We say that a geodesic is (future ) inextendible if there exist no (future) endpoint for example. Wouldnt that imply the domain of the geodesic is $[p, \infty)$ with some beginning point $p$? And it is incomplete if there is a gedesic with finite affine length, i.e. there exist inextendible geodesics (at least in one direction) but they only have a finite range of affine parameter. So the domain would be [p,b] for some b. How does this match if they are both? Isnt then every extendible curve incomplete, they also have finite length if there timelike measured with affine parameter $=$ proper time?

Comment: As far as I can remember, an incomplete geodesic is inextendible if the range of its affine parameter is not ($-\infty$, $\infty$). I'm not quite sure what you mean by an incomplete geodesic with finite affine length. An inextendible geodesic is incomplete if its affine length is $([a, \infty)$, which is not finite, this describes spacetime with a singularity which means we remove the singularity from the spacetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inextendibility** is referred to generic smooth curves defined in a (semi)open interval, for instance referring to the right bound: $\gamma: (a,b) \to M$. The curve is (right) inextendible if there is no $p\in M$ such that $\gamma(t)\to p$ as $t\to b$. I stress that $b$ is allowed to be $+\infty$. Notice that this definition is invariant under reparametrization. Obviously, changing the parametrization (through a bijective bi-differentiable map), $b$ becomes $b'$, but $p$ does not change.

**Completeness** is a property of a curve *with a specific choice of its parameter*.  Right completeness means that the domain of the parameter ranges till $+\infty$. An analogous def is valid for the left limit.

In general, the two notions are unrelated because the former does not depend on the choice of the parametrization whereas the latter depends. However they are related for geodesics also because the notion of geodesic includes a preferred choice of the parameter.

A geodesic, parametrized with an affine parameter,  can be inextendible even if $b<+\infty$. Think of a geodesic exiting $p$ at $t=0$   defined in the whole real line and next change the spacetime by removing a point on $\gamma$. The new geodesic is defined only in $(-\infty,b)$ and there is no limit point when appoaching $b$, as it whoud be just the removed point.

> Wouldn't that imply the domain of the geodesic is [p,∞) with some beginning point p?

Out of my comment above, the answer is no. I showed a future inextendible geodesic which is not complete.

However, it turns out that, if $b=+\infty$ then a geodesic is necessarily inextendible. This is due to the explicit  use of an affine parameter.

If you are dealing with a generic curve (in particular a geodesic described with a non affine parameter) with parameter varying in the whole $(a,+\infty)$, the curve can be still extendible according to the definition above.

> Isnt then every extendible curve incomplete,

If the curve is not a geodesic parametrised with an affine parameter, the answer is again no in general. $\gamma(t)=( e^{-t}, 1,1,1) \in R^4$ with $t\in (-\infty, +\infty)$ is extendible but complete.

Comment: Yes but we speak of incomplete inextendible geodesics. In my Definition there is no left or right completeness/ incompleteness, just complete or incomplete. So beeing incomplete is what i wrote in the question. How does this now mtach with beeing inextendible?

Comment: I added some further comments to my answer. I am not sure to understand your issues…

Comment: But you used other definitions than mine. So you get other resulst.

Comment: Ok,I am not able to understand your issues. Sorry.

Comment: In other words. Inextendible is clear, no endpoint, we assume its a future directed timelike curve  $\gamma \colon I \rightarrow M$ with no future endpoint. So it goes on and on forever. If this curve is now incomplete, we only have a finite range of affine parameter. So there has to be an $r \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $s<r$ for all $s \in I$. How can it be that it goes on forever but has a point where the domain ends?

Comment: Because inextendible does *not* mean that it goes ahead for an infinite amout of proper time. It simply means that there is no endpoint. My example where one removes an event from the spacetime should illustrate this fact.

Comment: The endpoint dont have to lie on the curve. So if the curve does not go on forever, we always find an endpoint.

Comment: I showed you a precise counterexample against  this idea "The endpoint dont have to lie on the curve. So if the curve does not go on forever, we always find an endpoint." So I cannot help you further. Sorry. Please stop here this discussion with me.

Comment: Oh yeah im sorry, now i get what you mean, my fault. But i have still a question at your example. In Hawking and Ellis is written in short, incomplete = finite range of affine parameter. how can your curve from $(-\infty, b)$ be incomplete? The range is $\infty$. And your last example, how can you extend this curve? The parameter range is the whole real line, thats my Definition for beeing complete.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand well your new question since we have introduced too many examples, counterexamples and details. I suggest you to write from scratch a new independent  question in the clearest possible way.